How to lock the app that no one should uninstall
We are trying to implement a feature that no one can uninstall our app, because we are using the app for tracking purpose of our sales persons so that we can track them day in day out. We are using react-native for the development of app.
How could we implement this in our app...?

You will have to use some Mobile Device Management (MDM) solutions to meet your requirement. Enroll your device to some MDM solution, then you (or your organization) will have more control over the device. You can also use Android Management API to develop your own solution.

Without manufacturer support this is impossible .. and There are 100's of them ..

I want in such a way that, We only must know the password, the sales persons must not know that. If they want to uninstall the app they have to come to us

You need to use an MDM, such as Android Enterprise.  https://www.android.com/enterprise/   It will also need to be a device you own, not the user's personal phone.  Because installing an MDM is basically like rooting your device, it gives the MDM total control over it.

Use administration access. By following;
<receiver
android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
    android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />

Use react-native-background-geolocation

I tried this but it's not working

This is a dated way of doing things,  Android Enterprise is the more modern way.
